# Does Rakish Audacity improve or change your Initiative bonus?

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue, initiative

The Swashbuckler Rogue's Rakish Audacity (found in Xanathar's Guide to Everything) says:

> You can give yourself a bonus to your initiative
>   rolls equal to your Charisma modifier.

Is this meant to be instead of the Dexterity modifier, or on top of it?

**A Swashbuckler Rogue with 3 DEX and 2 CHA rolls 10 in their initiative d20. What is their final initiative value?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## With Rakish Audacity, an initiative roll is d20+Dex+Cha

An initiative roll is, by definition a Dexterity check:

> When combat starts, every participant makes a Dexterity check to determine their place in the initiative order.

Thus, an initiative roll will, by default always involve adding your Dexterity modifier (unless a feature tells you otherwise).

Rakish Audacity defines itself not as a replacement to that Dexterity modifier, but as a bonus to that roll:

> You can give yourself a **bonus to your initiative rolls** equal to your Charisma modifier.

Since Rakish Audacity says that is is a bonus to that roll, it gets added on top of that normal Dexterity check.

So, for your specific example, the initiative check would be: $$10(d20) + 3(DEX) +2(CHA) = 15 $$

---

[Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/826212666066685953) has clarified via Twitter and agrees with this interpretation:

> Initiative is a Dexterity check. Rakish Audacity lets you add your Cha. mod. to that check; it doesn't replace the Dex. check.

Comment: Add alert and you will always go first